# Cannot get signal out of GeForce 9800 GTX while installed

Tags: video, graphics-card, signal

I am installing an EVGA GeForce 9800 GTX into one of my PCs but I cannot get a video signal out of it while it is installed. The computer works fine while the graphics card is not in it's PCIe slot, but when it and it's two 6-pin power connectors are installed, there is no signal on either my monitor or TV, even using HDMI or VGA from the motherboard. The graphics card does work because the fan works when booting. I am trying to install the GeForce Experience drivers but it requires the graphics card to be installed before continuing the installation of the drivers.

Comment: Have you checked that your BIOS is configured to allow graphics output to the PCIe slots?

Comment: The only clue that the card words is the fan spins?  That's a poor diagnostic.  Where did the card come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resting the computer on it's side (motherboard closest to the ground) fixed the issue. The issue happened because there was not a screw holding the card in it's PCIe port.